# Can't create DataTable in powershell accsessing by classname

Tags: windows, visual-studio, powershell

I'm trying to create DataTable and DataColumn objects in powershell.
I added this in the beggining of my script

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Data
```

But when I try to call this part of code

```
$DataTable = New-Object -TypeName DataTable $TableName
```

I got an error

> New-Object : Cannot find type [DataTable]: verify that the assembly
>   containing  this type is loaded.

What can be the problem? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to do this:

```
$DataTable = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.DataTable $TableName
```

Comment: But can I do this without writing full path to class? I mean, to declare only DataTable?

Comment: I don't know. Why does it matter?

Comment: This is task from university and it says that I should import namespace and use classname

Comment: `System.Data.DataTable` is the class name.

Comment: `DataTable` is class name. `System.Data` is namespace which contains type definition/class `DateTable`. `System.Data.DataTable` is called full class name or qualified class name, it contains namespace and class name. You can load assembly to import classes definied in namespaces. But in PowerShell you need to use full class name in many cases especially when you want to create an instance.

Answer (score 0):

You missed a part of the namespace. Should be like this:

```
$table = New-Object Data.DataTable('TableName')
$table.Columns.Add('Column1') | Out-Null
```

Or:

```
$table = New-Object -TypeName 'Data.DataTable' -ArgumentList 'TableName'
```

Or:

```
$table = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Data.DataTable' -ArgumentList 'TableName'
```

Or:

```
$table = [Data.DataTable]'TableName'
```

The first "System" word from full namespace can be always ommited in PowerShell.